# When creating a new uvmap for an object the previous uvmaps are included. How do I start without them?

Tags: uv-image-editor

I'm having a hard time managing my uvmaps.  I keep getting artifacts from previous uvmaps showing up.  I unwrap only a portion of my object to place a decal.  I make a new uvmap and the previous one shows up and so on.  And I can't remove it.  I need help bad.  Either this is buggy or I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

So I just made a new uvmap "UVMap" and it auto included the other uvmaps.  And I can't figure out how to get rid of them.  Why they appear.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a [new uvmap](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/layout_management.html#uv-maps-panel), duplicates the selected uvmap.

You can change any uvmap layout without altering any other uvmaps, just choose a different [mapping type](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/unwrapping/mapping_types.html) from the unwrap menu or adjust the uv positions the way you want them.

If you want to completely reset a uvmap - in edit mode select all <kbd>A</kbd> and then press <kbd>U</kbd> and select [*Reset*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/unwrapping/mapping_types.html#reset).

Comment: I understand that creating a new uvmap will duplicate the selected uvmap.   But can I get rid of it?  I tried the reset and did not get rid of it.

Comment: reset will reset the uv positions back to un unwrapped uv layout. To delete a uvmap you use the `-` button to delete it.

Comment: the "-"?  omg thanks!  so random.  I guess they needed the del key for something else.

Comment: oh i knew how to delete an entire uvmap.  I wanted to delete parts of a uvmap in the uv image/editor.  But I don't think it is possible.  I think the uvmaps just accumulate in the uv image/editor as you add sections.

Comment: @deanresin All verts in a model are represented in a uv layout, you can select some uv's in the uv editor and use `S` `0` to move them all to the same point, effectively using a single (transparent?) pixel for the chosen uv's.